# Does a statement of the form "for all $X>0$ there exists $x > X$ satisfying some condition" evaluate to "the condition must be true for all $x>0$"?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Question is essentially as the title states. I was inspired by the form which the negation of the Cauchy Criterion takes.

If I have a statement saying "$P$ is only true if for all $X > 0$, there exists an $x > X$ for which $Q$ is true," does this logically evaluate to "$P$ is only true if $Q$ is true for all $x > 0$"?

The original may take the form of $$P\iff \forall X>0\;\exists x\geq X :Q$$

In theory, one may sketch a proof proceeding by induction, where one might say that since *for all* $X$ there must be an $x > X$ making $Q$ true, $Q$ must be true for $X = 0.5$ and $x = 1$, and $X = 1$ and $x = 2$, etc. Thus $Q$ must be true for all $x$.

Is this logically permissible?

Comment: Consider if $P$ is true only for even integers

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Apologies -- I'm afraid I may not fully understand -- it is demanded that P is true iff for *all* X there is an x $\geq$ X such that Q is true. I'm not sure how to go about restricting to the case x $\in$ {2,4,6...}. Is it that Q would take some form so that it is only true for x which are greater than or equal to given X, and members of that set; thus, P is also only true with such an x? In such a case, I can see what you're describing.

Comment: For every integer $X>0$, there exists an integer $x>X$ that is even. That does not entail that every positive integer is even.

Comment: I suggest someone write the $1^{st}$ and $3^{rd}$ comments out as an answer/self answer.

Comment: Please put your question into the question part of the post, not the title.

Comment: The statement means that that you can find arbitrarily high $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true.  So, you can require $x$ to be as big as you want and still find $x$ so that $P(x)$ is true.  In the context of natural numbers, this is the same as saying *there are infinitely many $x$ such that $P(x)$* is true.  For example: That there are infinitely prime numbers means that for any $N$, we can find a prime $p> N$. It's not equivalent, though, for the domain of real numbers. (exercise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.  Say $P(x)$ is true only if $x$ is an even integer.  ($P$ and $Q$ could even both be “$x$ is even.” )  Then it is true that, for all $X$, there is $x>X$ such that $P(x)$, but it is not true that, for all $X$, $P(X)$.